# jQuery validation script and overlay preventing page from 'submitting'

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have am using the jQuery validation plugin (1.8.1 from MS CDN) to validate input fields on the submit of a form. The script is 1000+ lines in all and although gives a nice approach to validating fields (yes I check with php after the fact as well) I am thinking about tossing it regardless. I have got it to a point where the script runs well.

### Update - final code, working.

Code has been updated but I am still running into issues. Now, the submit function works but it never validates the fields. (I know it is reaching the fields with a simple alert() test placed after the length check:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

  $('#page_submit').click(function() {
    $('#signupform').submit(); 
  });

  if ($("#signupform").length > 0) { 
    $("#signupform").validate({ 
        rules: {
            fname: 'required',
            lname: 'required',
            websitename: 'required',
            address: 'required',
            city: 'required',
            state: 'required',
            zip: { required: true, digits: true },
            password: 'required',
            passwordconf: 'required',
            email: { required: true, email: true }
        },
        messages: {
            fname: 'Your first name is required.',
            lname: 'Your last name is required.',
            email: { required: 'Your email address is required.',
            email: 'Please enter a valid email address.'}
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('body').append('<div id="cboxOverlay"></div>');
            $('#cboxOverlay').show();
            form.submit();
        }
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

NOTE: The above code has been modified and now works. The submit() function MUST be added after the click function in this scenario because we are clicking an image and adding the submit action, not a submit button within a form.

Previously, I had action placed on the button image itself but moved up into the jquery statement to prevent obstrusive JS. When clicking the button now, the page submits automatically and never runs the validation.

Comment: "//code block//... No problem here."  I see a big problem.  I see obtrusive JavaScript, the very issue jQuery was created to address.

Comment: @Adam Terlson - Can you explain more? What's wrong with using the validation plugin?

Comment: @Adam Terlson - care to expound on your comment?

Comment: @JM4 - I wasn't referring to an issue with your plugin use, but instead how you are "attaching" events to your button click event:  `onClick="$('#signupform').submit(); return false;"` should instead be unobtrusive, meaning out of your HTML and bound like such: `$('#yourbutton').click(function(e) { $('#signupform').submit(); e.preventDefault(); });`  Simply removing the `return false;` and replacing it with the `e.preventDefault()` might just fix your problem, but that's only a guess.  Here's some helpful further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: good advice, however - implemented the original way worked. The updated method does not. I can provide code but my assumption lies with the preventdefault (with or without, an alert sample can be issued and the page is submitted regardless.

Comment: @Adam Terlson - code has been updated based on your recommendation to move the js click action into the jquery ready function but the page submits on its own regardless now.

Comment: If it works obtrusively, there is **never** a reason it won't work unobtrusively except for an error in your code.  I strongly suggest for your own knowledge and code cleanliness you learn the proper way to bind events in JavaScript.  If it's still submitting, you may need to add `e.stopPropagation()` as well.  Eventing is another important concept in JS, and it's important to learn why you should stop misusing `return false;`  http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: thanks for the link, though I have not used return false in the script anywhere? I can create a JSfiddle but neither e.preventdefault or e.stoppropagation() resolved the error. Page submits regardless. As I mention, if there was a flaw in the JS altogether, nothing would execute and the alert test would not fire.

Comment: You've misunderstood a lot here.  The `return false` was in your obtrusive `onclick` property. You've also bound your events wrong (you bound your submit event after calling `.submit()` for some reason...), which is why it is not working.  I strongly suggest reading up on unobtrusive principles and how to properly bind and handle events in JavaScript/jQuery.  Good luck.

Comment: Your call to Validate() is binding function to events, such as the submit event, which you're calling _prior_ to calling Validate() with your form.submit() call.  Clearly this will not work.  And I disagree with your logic entirely when the code that "works" is poorly written and not easily maintained.  In such scenarios, it's entirely worth it to learn the proper way and write it correctly.  It should take mere minutes, not hours.

Comment: Valid point on proper code. To assume it would take somebody with very little knowledge of JS let alone jquery minutes is asinine but that is another point. I solved the issue in that, YES submit has to be called before form.submit() for it to work. Validate ONLY works on the presence of a submit action (which if not declared will never exist because it is an image, not a submit button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have to submit the form, yes?

```
    submitHandler: function(form) {  
        $('body').append('<div id="cboxOverlay"></div>');
        $('#cboxOverlay').show();
        form.submit();  //*******************
    }
```

Comment: omg, my bad. Thank you for helping me recognize this. Although, I am surprised the form is not automatically submitted on success regardless. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Wouldn't he then be calling submit twice?  Why wouldn't calling it again just create a nice infinite loop since he apparently got to that function by calling $().submit() in the first place?

Comment: @Adam Terlson - it is my understanding, the submit() function is disabled once the validation script is run so it must therefore be called again (hence my comment above though, seems submithandler would have this built in).

Comment: note - according to jquery docs, it must be called directly: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

Comment: Note: once this is implemented, submit functionality does not work in iOS for some reason. Yet to be discovered as to why.